# Fine Tuning / Correcting my custom Paging in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Currently I have tsql stored procedure which retrieves data based on each page request. I pass in parameters: PageIndex & PageSize as below:

```
@ColNames VARCHAR(1000), @PageIndex INT = 1, @PageSize INT = 100

DECLARE @s_query VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @RecordCount INT;

SET @s_query = 
'Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ' + @ColNames + ') AS ##RowNum, '+@ColNames+' INTO ##Results' +
' FROM Table1 U
Inner Join Date D on U.DateID = D.DateID            
ORDER BY D.DateID DESC';

EXEC (@s_query);

SET @s_query =  
'SELECT ' + @ColNames + ' FROM ##Results
WHERE ##RowNum BETWEEN('+CONVERT(varchar(20),@PageIndex)+'-1) * '+CONVERT(varchar(20),@PageSize)+' + 1 
AND((('+CONVERT(varchar(20),@PageIndex)+' -1) * '+CONVERT(varchar(20),@PageSize)+' + 1) + '+CONVERT(varchar(20),@PageSize)+') - 1';

EXEC (@s_query);
```

The above works fine but my problem/question is: The returned results (100 rows) is not sorted by Date as in the first s_query above. I need the result tobe sorted by date. I guess in the second query where I am selecting the pagesize results it is doing it randomly. Can someone point me to my fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set ordering in the ROW_NUMBER part. There is also no need to apply query ordering in your first query (remove the ending ORDER BY, the ordering is already done by ROW_NUMBER function and you should order by this column in the second query to apply correct ordering for your paging).

Corrected code:

```
DECLARE @ColNames VARCHAR(1000), @PageIndex INT = 1, @PageSize INT = 100

DECLARE @s_query VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @RecordCount INT;


SET @s_query = 
'Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY D.DateID DESC) AS RowNum, '+@ColNames+' INTO ##Results ' +
'FROM Table1 U ' +
'Inner Join Date D on U.DateID = D.DateID';

EXEC (@s_query);

SET @s_query =  
'SELECT ' + @ColNames + ' FROM ##Results ' +
'WHERE RowNum BETWEEN ('+ CAST((@PageIndex-1)*@PageSize+1 AS nvarchar(20)) + ' AND ' + CAST(@PageIndex*@PageSize AS nvarchar(20)) + ') ' +
'ORDER BY RowNum ';

EXEC (@s_query);
```

Optimized code (there is no need to use temp table and no need to join the date table):

```
DECLARE @ColNames VARCHAR(1000), @PageIndex INT = 1, @PageSize INT = 100

DECLARE @s_query VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @RecordCount INT;


SET @s_query = 
'
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateID DESC) AS RowNum
        , ' + @ColNames + ' 
    FROM 
        Table1
)

SELECT
    ' + @ColNames + '
    ,TotalRowCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1)
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    RowNum BETWEEN ('+ CAST((@PageIndex-1)*@PageSize+1 AS nvarchar(20)) + ' AND ' + CAST(@PageIndex*@PageSize AS nvarchar(20)) + ') 
ORDER BY
    RowNum 
';

EXEC (@s_query);
```

Comment: Saso I tried the above but does not work. The ordering is not even happening on the first page. The dates are not ordered

Comment: that's strange. have you checked the values of U.DateID? does the RowNo column in ##Results increase like it should (based on the DateID DESC)?

Comment: i think the problem is the `WHERE RowNum ...` part in the second query. why are you not calculating the values and inserting values (not formulas) into the dynamic SQL code? e.g. 
`WHERE RowNum BETWEEN ('+ CAST((@PageIndex-1)*@PageSize+1 AS nvarchar(20)) + ' AND ' + CAST(@PageIndex*@PageSize AS nvarchar(20)) + ')'`

Comment: I've updated the code in my answer. Please try it out. Based on my test, this should work.

Comment: saso thanks it works. my last question: is there a different way of doing this as sometimes my data is very large with 3 million rows and each time it does paging it goes through the 3 million rows - there must be a better way of doing this.

Comment: there is no need to have 2 queries at the first place. what you are doing now is sorting and inserting the entire table into a global temp table every time and then querying a very narrow recordset from there. you can use a single query (using CTE). There is also no need to join Date table as you're using DateID to sort (and D.DateID = U.DateID)

Comment: saso one little modification in the optimized code above: how can i add a column to the results "total no of rows" from the select. As before i used to use: SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*) FROM ##Results. is there a way for this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57088/discussion-between-user2906420-and-saso).

Comment: you can add it to the list of returned columns in the query. i've modified the code, take a look. otherwise, we can continue in chat if you have more questions. ;)

Comment: Saso - I just realised if I add a Where condition in the optimized code above in the WITH cte brackets it throws an error: it cannot find the column. However we do have the "@ColNames" in the select statement.

Answer (score 0):

SQL data has no order, other than that specified by an `order by` clause, which you are missing.

Add an `order by` clause to the end of the second query, specifying the order you want.

The `order by` clause in the first query is doing nothing, so you may as well remove it.

Comment: I have removed the order by in the first query and added "ORDER BY Date DESC" to the second where Date col is in @ColNames variable. However there is no difference: In page1 I get back dates "02/05/2014" and then in Page2 "06/05/2014" so definitely not sorting

Comment: Is Date the only column in colnames?

Comment: No there are other cols including Name,Address,Details - what is the best efficient approach to this ?

Comment: have you tested the solution i posted?

Comment: The best approach is to set the rownumber based on the order you want, and to page it by the results.

Comment: podiluska can you provide an example to help. I tried to set the rownumber ORDER BY D.DateID DESC. and then in the second query I ORDER BY ##RowNum by not working even in the first page.

Comment: @user2906420 What is `dateid` in your query?